# Twitter icon missing on the profile page of the network sites

Tags: support, design, profile-page

[image: missing twitter icon]

When I first started seeing this, I thought this could be some render because of poor internet error that time or whatever. I basically ignored it. I think its a issue which was okay few weeks ago I guess.

Comment: This is a simple SVG path. It works fine in Firefox Nightly 68.0a1 on Arch Linux with Gnome 3.32.0. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome, version 73.0.3683.86, on Windows and elementary OS. Both up-to-date to the latest build.

Comment: The icon does have an `iconTwitter` class name. Does it work if you disable any ad-blocker or other add-ons? Make sure you configure your ad filters properly.

Comment: I see, the icon seems to work after disabling ad blocker.

Comment: That probably means you have enabled some “social media blocker” list or similar which blocks icons with a class name of `iconTwitter` or perhaps anything containing “Twitter” (same for “Facebook”, etc.). Maybe you can set Stack Exchange as an exception somehow.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is now resolved after disabling ad-blocker / adding site to exception list. There's nothing wrong with the site. It was working few days back (maybe 1 week) and when it stopped working, without checking things properly I thought this is something with the site.

Thanks to @[Sebastian Simon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/289905/xufox). According to him,

> That means, you probably have enabled some “social media blocker” or similar which blocks icons with a class name of iconTwitter or perhaps anything containing “Twitter” (same for “Facebook”, etc.). Maybe you can set Stack Exchange as an exception somehow.